# Writing TXT file in PHP, want to insert the new line in the beginning

Tags: php, file

Is that possible to insert a new line in a .txt file at the beginning?

I learned that using `fwrite(filename, sentence)` is adding a new line at the end.

But I am wondering is there any method to add a new line at the beginning, like if my original .txt file is

```
AAA
```

When I add a new line "BBB", it looks like

```
BBB
AAA
```

Comment: It is not possible to "prepend" data to a file because of how everything is stored on disk. You will need to write the whole file after string that you are adding.

Comment: @Dimi not 100% true, prepend in this context is to mean how can we prepend and store to the disk - not necessarily instantly prepend the file, I think possibly needs the comment amending to make it clearer that it is possible, it's just not a one liner (or a readable one liner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `file_get_contents()` to get the original data first, then prepend your string to that:

```
$existing = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.txt');
$fp = fopen('/path/to/file.txt', 'w');    

$myString = 'hello world'. PHP_EOL;

fwrite($fp, $myString. $existing);
fclose($fp);
```

here we open the file with `w` - to fully overwrite, not append. Because of this, we need to get the file contents before the `fopen()`.
Then we get the existing file contents and concat it to your string, and overwrite the file.

**Edit: file_put_contents() - as suggested by Nigel Ren**

```
$existing = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.txt');
$myString = 'hello world'. PHP_EOL;

file_put_contents('/path/to/file.txt', $myString. $existing);
```

**Edit: function to create one-liner**

```
function prepend_to_file(string $file, string $data)
{
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        try {
            file_put_contents($file, $data. file_get_contents($file));

            return true;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception($file. ' couldn\'t be amended, see error: '. $e->getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception($file. ' wasn\'t found. Ensure it exists');
    }
}

# then use:
if (prepend_to_file('/path/to/file.txt', 'hello world')) {
    echo 'prepended!';
}
```